# connect to sql ce database from sql server 2008 stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-ce

I have an 3.5 CE database on `d:/sampleDB.sdf`. I want to write stored procedure in MS SQL Server 2008 Database Engine to insert some(any) data to CE database(*sdf* file).

I want tsql method (no C#, no ado.net) *to connect or use* sql ce database.

Thanks.

Comment: See my blog pots here: http://erikej.blogspot.com/2008/10/accessing-sql-compact-from-sql-server.html - if that is really what you want to do??